# wildcard search in query_string

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a filterbar therefore I am using query_string. I have no idea what user will write into filter bar. I need to use also wildcard search.

Let say that filed is `attr: aaa bbb`.

When I search for `attr:aa*`, it works.

When I search for `attr:"aa*"`, it works.

When I search for `attr:"aaa b*"`, it doesn't work. Why?

My attribute has this mapping:

```
  "attr": {
        "index": true,
        "type": "keyword"
 },
```

And example of query

```
{"size":1,"track_total_hits":true,"query":{"bool":{"must":[{"query_string":{"query":"attr:aaa","analyze_wildcard":true}},...
```

Comment: can you share result of _analyze API against the indices that has this doc and "aaa bbb"? https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html

Comment: {
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "aaa bbb*",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "word",
      "position" : 0
    }
  ]
}